# Vue / Vite v3.2.5 - Invalid value "umd" for option "output.format"

Tags: vuejs2, vite

I use Vue2 with Vite v3.2.5 and when I run npm run build I get this error: ***Invalid value "umd" for option "output.format" - UMD and IIFE output formats are not supported for code-splitting builds.***

That's my vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue2';
const path = require('path')
import { resolve } from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            hotFile: 'public/widget.hot',
            input: [
                'resources/js/app.js',
                'resources/scss/app.scss',
                'resources/scss/index.scss'
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
        },
        dedupe: [
            'vue'
        ]
    },
    alias: {
        '~bootstrap': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap'),
    },
    build: {
        cssCodeSplit: true,
        lib: {
            input: {
                app: "./resources/js/app.js"
            },
            entry: resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/app.js'),
            output: {
                path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
                filename: 'bundle.js',
            },
            name: 'bundle',
            fileName: 'app'
        },
        rollupOptions: {
            external: ['vue'],
            output: {
                globals: {
                    vue: 'Vue',
                },
                format: "esm",
                inlineDynamicImports: false,
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Does anyone know what's the problem here? My output.format value is "esm" and not "umd" ?!
Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you tried specifying `format: esm` inside the `build.lib.output` object?

Comment: Yes, but it's not working. Then I get the same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the `lib` option is specified, it looks like Vite defaults to generating `es` and `umd` bundles:

> Running vite build with this config uses a Rollup preset that is oriented towards shipping libraries and produces two bundle formats: es and umd (configurable via build.lib):

(from https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode)

To change this, you have to add an explicit `formats` option inside `build.lib`:

```
        lib: {
            input: {
                app: "./resources/js/app.js"
            },
            formats: ['es'],
            entry: resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/app.js'),
            output: {
                path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
                filename: 'bundle.js',
            },
            name: 'bundle',
            fileName: 'app'
        },
```

Comment: Glad I could help! It'd be great if you could mark my answer as accepted :)